# What is google sheets maximum access limit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i currently have a google web app that takes a value then checks it against 14,0000 cells in a master google sheet. i've had the idea to break the function down into 14 functions that run simultaneously(each function searching 1000) therefore cutting the runtime from 6 seconds to below 1. The issue i am concerned about is the limit of 30 simultaneous functions running. this web app will be used by more than one person at a time so it needs to be able to do more than 30. My idea is to create an account for each user with a copy of the web app for each account, so that the simultaneous executions will stay around 14 for each user. so my question is this, Does google sheets have a limit to the amount of simultaneous read/write? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can implement this I think there are no limits.

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per
>   100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.
>   Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily
>   usage limit.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits